# Magento 2 - Choose payment method for one checkout programmatically

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, programmatically, magento-2.2.1

#### Question (+ TL;DR)

Is it possible to choose programmatically specific payment method only for actual checkout process, like - one time choice?

#### Some context:

I'm developing a plugin for magento related to installments and I want to add a button to product page responsible for choosing a particular payment option. I need to implement a behavior for a button that adds a product to  cart, redirects to cart and if user decides to go through checkout, a particular payment method will be already selected (payment through installments).

#### What I've done

As there is plenty of information about how to take care of adding product to cart programmatically or redirecting somewhere, unfortunately I haven't managed to find any information about the last thing I need here. Here is source of controller that does mentioned things:

`Controller\customcontroller\Index.php`, in execute():

```
$params = array(
    'form_key' => $formKey,
    'product' => $productId,
    'qty' => 1,
);
$this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$this->cart->save();

$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$resultRedirect->setUrl("/checkout/cart");

return $resultRedirect;
```